# Proof For Linear System Solution Sets

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm confused as to how to approach or prove this problem. Any help would be useful thank you.
Given the linear system $AX = B$, where $B \neq O$. If $X_1$ is a solution to the given linear system and $X_2$ is a solution to the associated homogeneous system $AX = O$, then $X_1+X_2$ is also a solution to $AX = B$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that by the linearity we have:
$$A(x_{1}+x_{2})=Ax_{1}+Ax_{2}$$

But since $x_2$ is a solution of $Ax=0$ and $x_1$ is a solution for $Ax=B$ we get:
$$Ax_{1}+Ax_{2}=Ax_{1}+0=B$$